# TesseractError: (2, 'Usage: pytesseract [-l lang] input_file') error

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am getting the error TesseractError: **(2, 'Usage: pytesseract [-l lang] input_file')**. Using ! sudo apt install but still getting the error in colab.
Its a JPG I am trying to read.

-----------------------------code -------------------------------------

```
! apt install tesseract-ocr
! apt install libtesseract-dev
! sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
! pip install Pillow
! pip install pytesseract
import pytesseract
import shutil
import os
import cv2
import random
from google.colab import files
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image,ImageFilter
!pip install pdf2image
!apt-get install -y poppler-utils
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
#from google.colab import drive
!sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
!pip install pytesseract
!pip install tesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/usr/local/bin/pytesseract'
image_path_in_colab = 'Pillow block drawing.jpg'
img = cv2.imread('Pillow block drawing.jpg')
custom_config = r'-l eng --psm 6'
pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=custom_config)
extractedInformation = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(image_path_in_colab))
print(extractedInformation)
```

Comment: Hey, try changing `pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=custom_config)` to pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')

Answer (score 9):

install:

```
!sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
```

Change:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/usr/local/bin/pytesseract'
```

to:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/usr/bin/tesseract'
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the tesseract location as env variable . Like this

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/usr/bin/tesseract'
```

The following line is wrong

> pytesseract.pytesseract.**tesseract**_cmd =
> r'/usr/local/bin/**pytesseract**'